# Using 'save' and 'cancel' button in cell editing for Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag-grid in my Angular application and the data in the grid is populated from a web service. I implemented cell editing in this grid, so when I click one of the columns then the entire row will be editable and when i click outside the grid stops editing. The following is the code in html and the component file:

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" class="ag-theme-balham left" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                            [gridOptions]="gridOptions" rowSelection="multiple" pagination=true (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)">
                        </ag-grid-angular>
```

component.ts file:

```
this.gridOptions = {
                defaultColDef: {
                    editable: (event: any) => {
                        if (this.isGridDataEditable) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false; // true/false based on params (or some other criteria) value
                        }
                    },
                    filter: true
                },
                singleClickEdit: true,
                stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus: true,
                paginationPageSize: 20,
                editType: 'fullRow',
                onCellValueChanged: (event: any) => {
                },
                onRowValueChanged: (event: any) => {
                },
                onRowEditingStopped: (event: any) => {
                }
            };
        }
```

The column definitions are generated dynamically based on the response from the web api. When the editing stops if the data changes then I have to make a call to the web api to update the data, all this is working as expected.But I would like to add a save and cancel button just above the grid and when the user clicks on save only then make the call to the web api, clicking on cancel button should revert the grid data back to the old values. I came across the api stopEditing(true) but it did not work. Could you please let me know how I could achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting `stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus` to `false`.

Then add two buttons above the grid, Save and Cancel.

On clicking save. call `onSave` function whose definition will be

```
onSave() {
  this.agGrid.api.stopEditing();
  this.callWebApi();
}
```

On clicking cancel, call `onCancel` function whose definitions will be

```
onCancel() {
  this.agGrid.api.stopEditing(true);
}
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for, what happens if for example, I have an error message from the API, business rule validation. How to "cancel" the changes on the row after the "stopEditing" ? I'm looking at getting the values from "getEditingCells" instead, but then I have to left-right a bit and I'm trying to avoid that. Thanks!

Comment: @SébastienRicher  ```stopEditing()``` takes an optional boolean parameter that you can use to signal that the edit should be cancelled instead of saved.